# Memcached, 1 server down but not using other one

Tags: c#, memcached

Hi All: Trying to use Memcached using BeIT.Memcached c# client.

My config entry:

```
<add key="MyCaching" value="server-a, server-b" />
```

Question is:

1. When server-a is down, BeIT.MemCached does not automatically go to server-b esp. for setting cache? I understand that since server-a is down, all the cache goes away. But new cache set request should redirect to server-b, right?
2. I am assuming this is client issue.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..I understand now. It didn't make sense initially, but does now.

Here:

1. BeIT.MemCached uses server selection algorithm to store the cache.
2. When server-a is down, returns null. So there is no such thing like automatic routing to server-b.
3. Set cache is going to fail as well since server selection algorithm will be still returning server-a even though that is down.

Answer to my question:

1. server-a is down for temporary reasons and the idea is to make it online
   ASAP. So cache continues to work after some failures (it is just the hit ratio). So application still continue function but peaks its usage based on what it does.
2. If server-a is going to be down for some more time, the best thing is to update the configuration file to remove "server-a" from the pooling, so that other servers are going to be used.